# Using the value of a variable in other parts of the code ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm making an API that has a `Video` entity that has a `ContentPath` variable.

```
    public class Video
    {
        public string ContentPath { get; set; }
    }
```

This variable is a string inserted via POST/PUT request, and ideally it should be the path to some file I'm going to download.

For example: `{ "ContentPath":"Files/Image.png" }`

My question is: how can I use the value of the variable `ContentPath` in other parts of my solution? More specifically, I need to replace the string `"Files/Image.png"` in the following chunk of code.

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/servers/{serverId}/videos")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VideosController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly string filePath;
        public VideosController(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}/binary")]
        public FileContentResult GetBinary()
        {
            // I need to replace the string "Files/Image.png" here for the ContentPath variable.
            return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), "application/octet-stream", "Files/Image.png");
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<ServerContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("Server"));
            services.AddDbContext<VideoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("Video"));
            // I need to replace the string "Files/Image.png" here for the ContentPath variable.
            services.AddSingleton(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Files/Image.png"));
        }
```

Comment: For startup.cs code you can define the value in appsettings.json file and read from there. And for get method you need to pass the variable as parameter to the method

Comment: Can't you just save this path in a database? Every other way of doing this would reset this value on application restart or wouldn't support having multiple instances. Also setting this value in a POST call is breaking the idempotency of your GetBinary() call. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `IOption<T>` pattern

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

1. Create a class which contains your Path property
2. Call `Configure<YourClass>(Configuration.GetSection("YourSection");` in `ConfigureServices`
3. Inject `IOptions<YourClass>` in your Controller

If you don't want to add the section to your config file, it also supports default values in the class which you can override depending on your configuration setup.